# Birthday notifications on Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar, google-calendar-reminders

How can I setup notifications for Birthdays on google calendar? 
Apparently, I can't.

[image: Google Calendar Birthday Settings]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Birthdays calendar is a special calendar. As you saw it doesn't include the several setting options like notifications.

If you want to get a Birthday notification, then copy the event to one of the calendars create by you and set the notifications on that calendar or for that specific event.

Answer (score 0):

It can´t be done. The easiest workaround is to click on the birthday event and choose "Duplicate" as seen in the image bellow. Then on the duplicated event set "Repeat anually" and add a notification with the desired anticipation.

[image: Calendar]

Comment: You don't want to click on 100s of birthday entries =) I think you have to use the export option instead: https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/settings/export?pli=1

Answer (score -2):

Apparently it can't be done in Google Calendar **BUT** you can achieve almost the same result by setting up [birthday reminders in Google Contacts](https://support.google.com/contacts/answer/12732221?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&oco=1#zippy=%2Ccreate-reminders-for-specific-dates).
(https://support.google.com/contacts/answer/12732221?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&oco=1#zippy=%2Ccreate-reminders-for-specific-dates)

At the moment, this feature only seems to be available on Android devices, but it's developing rapidly (there have been some significant improvements in the last few months), so it might be worth checking for updates.